# Swift can't call protocol method via delegate

Tags: ios, swift, macos, delegates, protocols

I have two classes. One class is named `ViewController` and the other class is named `TabView`.

My goal is to call a function `changeTab()` which is inside the TabView class from the ViewController.

Somehow I am having trouble with it because everytime my delegate is `nil`.

**Here is my code for ViewController:**

```
protocol TabViewProtocol: class {
    func changeTab() 
}

class ViewController: NSViewController {
    // delegate
    weak var delegateCustom : TabViewProtocol?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        print(delegateCustom) // outputs "nil"
    }

    buttonClickFunction() {
        print(delegateCustom) // outputs "nil"
        delegateCustom?.changeTab() // doesn't work
    }
}
```

**Here is my code for TabView:**

```
class TabView: NSTabViewController, TabViewProtocol {

    let myVC = ViewController()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        myVC.delegateCustom = self
    }

    func changeTab() {
        print("test succeed")
    }
}
```

Can someone explain me what I am doing wrong? - I am new to delegates and protocols...

Comment: You are always creating a new `ViewController` via `ViewController()` - that new controller probably has nothing to do with the rest of the app. You have to have some connection between the two instances - not create new instances. Generally that should be easily doable using the interface builder.

Comment: Updated my answer. This is how I had it before... Not working as well

Comment: And it is not working via the interfacebuilder because I am not using it. @luk2302

Comment: That code does not change a thing - you still create a new instance of the `ViewController` for the `TabView`. You have link two *existing* instances, not create new ones.

Comment: How do I do it then? It must also work programmatically not just in the interface builder @luk2302

Comment: You tell me - I do not know your project setup. I am telling you *what* you need to do. Unfortunately I cannot tell you *how* to do it because that is very general advice and in itself pretty self-explanatory.

Comment: Checkout this he is doing the same what I did ;) https://www.ralfebert.de/ios/swift-protocols-delegate/ @luk2302

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are using the delegate pattern wrongly. It is hard to tell which controller you want to define the protocol for and which one you want to adopt it - but here is one possible way.

```
// 1. Define your protocol in the same class file as delegate property.
protocol TabViewProtocol: class {
    func changeTab() 
}

// 2. Define your delegate property
class ViewController: NSViewController {
    // delegate
    weak var delegateCustom : TabViewProtocol?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        // It should be nil as you have not set the delegate yet.
        print(delegateCustom) // outputs "nil"
    }

    func buttonClickFunction() {
        print(delegateCustom) // outputs "nil"
        delegateCustom?.changeTab() // doesn't work
    }
}

// 3. In the class that will use the protocol add it to the class definition statement

class TabView: NSTabViewController, TabViewProtocol {

    let myVC = ViewController()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        myVC.delegateCustom = self

        // Should output a value now
        print(myVC.delegateCustom) // outputs "self"
    }

    func changeTab() {
        print("test succeed")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you are creating a new instance in this line:

```
let myVC = ViewController()
```

you should get existing instance of your ViewController.then set

```
myVC.delegateCustom = self
```